# JPEG library that supports variable quantization

Tags: image, jpeg

I have a set of images (photos). I want to convert them using lossy image compression (preferably JPEG, but I'm open for other possibilities). On each image there are some regions of interest, for which I would like to use lossless or near-lossless compression.

I thought I could use "variable quantization" (as defined in ITU-T recommendation T.84)  in JPEG format to set different quantization multipliers for blocks intersecting with my regions of interest than for other blocks.

I've tried IJG libjpeg and mozjpeg and it seems that neither of these libraries support variable quantization.

Do you know any open-source jpeg library that supports variable quantization?

Do you know any other image format that supports mixing lossy and lossless compression?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Dalija is right - unfortunately so, though, given that it's a highly specialized question.

Comment: You're not going to find a "standard" JPEG encoder that does this. JPEG presumes the quantization values for a blocks of a component are the same.

Comment: Given that storage is so cheap nowadays, it's hard to imagine circumstances under which it would make sense to do something so non-standard and jeopardise the ability to decode the images in the future. Could you maybe store the whole image at the lower quality for context and store any ROIs in separate files at a higher quality?

Comment: With a standard JPEG encoding, you're not going to be able to have variable quantization tables, but you can still reduce the quantity of high frequency A/C coefficients in select MCU blocks. The more A/C values you remove, the more detail is lost and the smaller the file becomes.